# multivariate bar chart in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

My data table looks like this:

```
table_name   expected_value  observed_value   
   <chr>          <dbl>          <dbl>  

 1 table1       95237608       95100229  
 2 table2        3014052        3014052     
 3 table3        3024749        3024749
```

I would like to create a multivariate bar chart to compare the `expected_value` and `observed_value` for each table.

Something looks like this:

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the examples in ggplot2 documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for doing so in ggplot first you have to change your format from wide to long, (tidyr::gather) then you map the aesthetics (choose the variables to be mapped) and finally you must use stat "identity" instead of the default "count",

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(table_name =c("a", "b","c"), expected=runif(3), observed=runif(3))
gather(df, key, value, -table_name) %>% ggplot(aes(table_name, value, fill=key)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]